# Why does robocopy still try to copy Thumbs.db even with XF option?

Tags: windows-10, robocopy, thumbs.db

Using robocopy (version 10.0.10586.0) on Windows 10 to copy files from one drive to another using the following command:

> ROBOCOPY c:\src D:\dest /MIR /COPY:DT /DCOPY:T /XJ /XF Thumbs.db /XD
>   "$RECYCLE.BIN" "System Volume Information" /MT:32 /R:0 /W:0 /V /TEE
>   /LOG:robocopy-log.txt

The xf switch is supposed to exclude the following file.  However for some reason it seems to ignore this and proceeds to choke (i.e. take a long time) on the Thumbs.db files and still seems to try to copy them.  Progress seems to get to about 30% of a given Thumbs.db file and the log output says "named" instead of "new file" for the thumbs.db.

As a workaround I deleted all the Thumbs.db in the source but ideally I wouldn't have to do that.

`del /ah /s Thumbs.db`

Comment: try *thumbs.db  ..

Comment: @Moab: do you mean with an asterisk or with lower case? I did already try the lowercase version which gave the same result.

Comment: @User I've run your command exactly and it stated it skipped 'Thumbs.db' - `Exc Files : Thumbs.db` - `Files :        Total 3        Copied 2        Skipped 1`. Can you update your question with the output you get from Robocopy?

Comment: use the asterisk